How to use 16-bit register addresses on the I2C bus in Toit?
When using Toit's Registers for I2C devices, register addresses are only 8 bit.
I have a device that uses 16-bit addresses. How can I communicate with it?

When using 16-bit addresses, one has to use the I2C device directly. That class has write-address and read-address functions that take the address as byte-array.
You can then use helper functions like the following:
read-register16 address/int size/int -> ByteArray:
  return device.read-address #[address >> 8, address & 0xff] size

write-register16 address/int bytes/ByteArray:
  device.write-address #[address >> 8, address & 0xff] bytes

